# Difference between unmanaged and struct constraints in c# generics

Tags: c#, generics

`where T : struct`  -Here T must be a value type.

`where T : Unmanaged` -Here T must not be a reference type.

What is the difference between struct and unmanaged if both are used for value types?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation on this, which part are you confused with?

Comment: Beginning with C# 7.3, you can use the unmanaged constraint to specify that the type parameter must be an unmanaged type. An unmanaged type is a type that is not a reference type and doesn't contain reference type fields at any level of nesting. The unmanaged constraint enables you to write reusable routines to work with types that can be manipulated as blocks of memory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/07/19/unmanaged-delegate-enum-type-constraints-c-7-3-rider-resharper/

> In order to satisfy the unmanaged constraint, a type must be a struct
>   and all the fields of the type must fall into one of the following
>   categories:
>
> - Have the type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, bool, IntPtr or UIntPtr.
> - Be an enum type.
> - Be a pointer type.
> - Be a user-defined struct that satisfies the unmanaged constraint.

So the unmanaged constraint is more constraining than the struct constraint.

Answer (score 1):

> The unmanaged constraint on generic type T enforces the type to be an
>   'unmanaged' struct that does not recursively contain reference type
>   fields. The concept of 'unmanaged types' existed in the C# language
>   for a long time and you can find this term in the C# language
>   specification and in the official documentation, but now the compiler
>   can actually enforce it.

More information, you can find in the official blog of Microsoft.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/06/12/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/

Answer (score 1):

To make it easy to understand:
`struct` means not accepts reference types, it only accepts "value types".
`Unmanaged` means only accepts pure value types, cannot conatans any reference type part.

For example:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int f1;
    public string f2;
}
```

This struct is legal in the `struct` constraint, but illegal in the `unmanaged` constraint.