# How can I Improve the Performance of comparing large Structs in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I want to compare a large Struct in C# via `Equals`, which in turn is implemented through `IEquatable<T>` Interface.
My Problem is that it performs very poorly, as my struct is rather large.
Imagine a simplified version of the struct like the follwoing:

```cs
public struct Data
{
    public byte b0;
    public byte b1;
    public byte b2;
    public byte b3;
    public byte b4;
    public byte b5;
    public byte b6;
    public byte b7;
}
```

I would now write a simple Equals:

```cs
public bool Equals(Data other)
{
    return b0 == other.b0 &&
           b1 == other.b1 &&
           ... 
}
```

Is there a way to make the Equals Method more efficient?

**Update**

My struct type is in [unmanaged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types) according to the definition given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55016923).

Comment: I have updated my Question. I am implementing `IEquatable<T>`, and theoretically it would not be problematic ot implement GetHashCode.

Comment: Can you demonstrate a benchmark where this performs poorly? Even with several dozen logical comparisons this will be quite fast. Are your structs several gigabytes in size?

Comment: No, but I need to do the comparision about ~10000 times with a struct in the kilobytes

Comment: You have 8 bytes which is a long.  Better to compare the long than individual bytes.  You can create an overlay in the structure so bytes are also handled as a long.  I would make the bytes an array.

Comment: It is not like I always have 8 bytes, this is just an example, does your solution also work with other structs?

Comment: Is your kilobyte-sized struct [unmanaged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55016923)?

Comment: What do you understand under unmanaged?

Comment: Yeah, It is according to your definition.

Comment: @user22829134 - basically, an unmanaged struct is one that recursively consists entirely of value-type primitives.  I.e. it can't include any managed references like `string someString;`.  If a struct is unmanaged it may be possible to create a `Span<T>` over it, cast that to a `Span<byte>`, then loop through the bytes.  But you can only do that if the struct is unmanaged.

Comment: Depending on your use case, moving from `&&` to `&` may reduce the code and increase the speed of your comparison.  It will remove the "should I short circuit this" test between every comparison. Instead, it will always do every comparison without any short circuit considerations.

Comment: I'm still curious about your worry about speed.  Compters are very good at doing something like `return b0 == other.b0 & bN == other.bN`.  They eat integer comparisons, AND operations (and possibly conditional jumps (if you use `&&`) for breakfast.  You'd need to do an awful lot of them before you'd notice

Comment: @Flydog57 OP is talking about structs several KB long. I'm 99% sure that the problem is not related to the code they are asking, but insane amount of unnecessary copying of the structs for method calls... I'm quite sure that none of the standard methods work ok with large structs as one need to sprinkle `ref` and take great care of avoiding extra copying...

Comment: Universal guidance is that a struct should not have more than 4 fields.  If more select a class instead.  If it is an interop type then give this class the [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] attribute.  First thing to do is to apply `in` to the Data parameter to look for an improvement.  Next, order the comparisons so the most-likely-to-be-different fields are tested first.

Comment: Your structs are way too big, wot. C# structs should be small enough so that copying them (which happens all the time because they're passed by value) should be very cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There in fact is a way to improve the performance of complex structs.

Taking your example:

```
public struct Data
{
    public byte b0;
    public byte b1;
    public byte b2;
    public byte b3;
    public byte b4;
    public byte b5;
    public byte b6;
    public byte b7;
}
```

Then you could write your `Equals` Method as follows:

```cs
public bool Equals(Data other)
{ 
    DatHelper helperThis = Unsafe.As<Data, DatHelper>(ref this); 
    DatHelper helperOther = Unsafe.As<Data, DatHelper>(ref other); 
    return helperThis.Equals(helperOther); 
}
```

With `DataHelper` looking somewhat like this:

```cs
public struct DataHelper
{
    public long l0;
    
    public bool Equals(DataHelper other)
    {
        return l0 == other.l0; 
    }
}
```

#### Why does this work?

> Well the important thing here is, that both structs have the same size in memory. We can then use `Unsafe.As` to reinterpret the memory of `Data` as `DataHelper`, which allows us to compare, in our case, one `long` with one `long`, instead of eight bytes with eight bytes.

This is extensible.
If you have for instance a struct, which is 33 bytes in size, then you could create `DataHelper` as four longs and one `byte` and compare them.

The only things that must be guaranteed are:

1. You must use a struct. This won't work with a class, as classes only contain the location of their data, while structs contain their actual data.
2. The size of your two structs must be the same.

As always, measure whether or not you actually see a performance gain.

Comment: Not sure why you need a struct, you could just cast to `Span<byte>` as shown in the other answer. Also very dependent on padding: the runtime could choose to implement it as separate `long`s.

Comment: You could of course handle the layout of the struct yourself with `StructLayout` Attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your kilobyte-sized structs are [unmanaged types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types) and you are working in [.NET Core 2.1 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-1#spant-and-memoryt), you can use [`MemoryMarshal.Cast()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast) along with [`MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.createreadonlyspan) to cast your each of your structs to a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`.  Having done so, you can compare them byte-by-byte for value equality:

```
public static class UnmanagedExtensions
{
    public static bool Equals<T>(ref T x, ref T y) where T : unmanaged
    {
        var byteSpanX = MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref x, 1));
        var byteSpanY = MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref y, 1));
        return byteSpanX.SequenceEqual(byteSpanY);
    }
}
```

If your structs have many, many fields, this is much simpler to implement than manually comparing them field by field.  Further note that, according to the [reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/MemoryExtensions.cs#L2410), `MemoryExtensions.SequenceEqual<T>(this ReadOnlySpan<T> span, ReadOnlySpan<T> other)` is *Unrolled and vectorized for half-constant input* so it is likely to be reasonably optimized.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QTY2O9) showing an 80-85% speedup vs `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals()`.

All that being said, if your structs really are *in the kilobytes* then it is likely you are spending an inordinate amount of time copying them around.  In its design guideline [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct), Microsoft states:

> CONSIDER defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the type are **small** and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in other objects.
>
> AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).
> - **It has an instance size under 16 bytes.**
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

A struct whose size is around a kilobyte is definitely not small.  Microsoft recommends using classes in such cases.  If you must use such a large struct (e.g. because you are interoperating with some unmanaged code) be sure to pass it by [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters#ref-parameter-modifier), [`ref readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters#ref-readonly-modifier) or [`in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters#in-parameter-modifier) whenever possible.

Comment: @Charlieface - `CreateReadOnlySpan<T>()` is generic, and according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.createreadonlyspan?view=net-7.0) the second parameter `length` is defined to be *The number of `T` elements that reference contains.*  So it should be 1 when you have a single `ref T` value, which is what we have here.  I suppose it could be larger e.g. if you had some fixed size array of structs.

Answer (score 1):

Took some of the suggestions posted here and my personal take via `Vector64`:

```
var len = Unsafe.SizeOf<Data>();
ViaVector(ref Unsafe.As<Data, byte>(ref left), ref Unsafe.As<Data, byte>(ref right), (uint)len)

public static bool ViaVector(ref byte first, ref byte second, uint length)
{
    nuint offset = 0;
    nuint lengthToExamine = length - (nuint)Vector64<byte>.Count;
    if (lengthToExamine != 0)
    {
        do
        {
            if (Vector64.LoadUnsafe(ref first, offset) != Vector64.LoadUnsafe(ref second, offset))
            {
                return false;
            }

            offset += (nuint)Vector64<byte>.Count;
        } while (lengthToExamine > offset);
    }

    if (Vector64.LoadUnsafe(ref first, lengthToExamine) == Vector64.LoadUnsafe(ref second, lengthToExamine))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And composed the [following benchmark](https://github.com/gurustron/playground/blob/master/csharp/SOAnswers/NET7/NET7Bench/Benchs/StructEqualityBench.cs):

```
public class StructEqualityBench
{
    private const int iterations = 10_000;

    private Data left = new()
    {
        b7 = 1
    };

    private Data right = new()
    {
        b7 = 1
    };

    [Benchmark]
    public bool AutoEquals()
    {
        var r = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            r |= left.Equals(right);
        }

        return r;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool ViaCustomEquals()
    {
        var r = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            r |= UnmanagedExtensions.CustomEquals(ref left, ref right);
        }

        return r;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool ViaVector()
    {
        var r = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            r |= UnmanagedExtensions.ViaVector(ref Unsafe.As<Data, byte>(ref left), ref Unsafe.As<Data, byte>(ref right), (uint)Unsafe.SizeOf<Data>());
        }

        return r;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool ViaDataHelper()
    {
        var r = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var helperThis = Unsafe.As<Data, DataHelper>(ref left);
            var helperOther = Unsafe.As<Data, DataHelper>(ref right);
            r |= helperOther.Equals(helperThis);
        }

        return r;
    }
}
```

Which gives "on my machine":

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AutoEquals | 144.292 us | 1.1918 us | 1.1149 us |
| ViaCustomEquals | 145.347 us | 0.3022 us | 0.2523 us |
| ViaVector | 54.058 us | 0.1327 us | 0.1176 us |
| ViaDataHelper | 5.285 us | 0.0134 us | 0.0119 us |

Notes:

- Based on sources [`ValueType.Equals`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueType.cs,37) should already be heavily optimized for case when:

  ```
  // if there are no GC references in this object we can avoid reflection
  // and do a fast memcmp
  ```

  Though note that depending on CLR implementation - [it can be a brittle heuristic](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/performance-implications-of-default-struct-equality-in-c/)
- My Vector approach is basically based on the approaches taken in this implementation - [@github.com](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0-rc.2.23479.6/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/SpanHelpers.Byte.cs#L821).
- The `DataHelper` approach seems to be the fastest one (on my hardware) but less extensible for different number of props.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I am not showing how to optimize the `Equals` method, but how to avoid writing it at all. You can simply define your struct as [`record struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#record-struct):

```
public record struct Data
{
    public byte b0;
    public byte b1;
    public byte b2;
    public byte b3;
    public byte b4;
    public byte b5;
    public byte b6;
    public byte b7;
}
```

This way the C# compiler will implement the `Equals` method for you:

```
public struct Data : IEquatable<Data>
{
    /* ... */

    [IsReadOnly]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public bool Equals(Data other)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<byte>.Default.Equals(b0, other.b0)
            && EqualityComparer<byte>.Default.Equals(b1, other.b1)
            && EqualityComparer<byte>.Default.Equals(b2, other.b2)
            && EqualityComparer<byte>.Default.Equals(b3, other.b3)
            && EqualityComparer<byte>.Default.Equals(b4, other.b4)
            && EqualityComparer<byte>.Default.Equals(b5, other.b5)
            && EqualityComparer<byte>.Default.Equals(b6, other.b6)
            && EqualityComparer<byte>.Default.Equals(b7, other.b7);
    }
}
```

[SharpLab demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDNgZmQb2QAjz2GXfbJfcnAEQEsBnABwBsBDATwGVqAvAUwB5KzAC7MAfAAoAlAG5ieAL5yc9AE7UAbsJ44ArgDtazAGbaocAGwEALFTpM2nXnwAqEyTgDuACx4rtznBBdPQBbZj1mAHMeYCVSCnwzAE5xABIAIkwhVnoeAHsjcWdJeRw6YLCI6OAccJrqIVocWm5tcswW3gKikpwAI1YhHlp0mSVS/GRFFCQoNBw/AGM8lRraIRUdRaEqYWYsJTn+we0+gAZZMkT5gaH+uEvyI9vTmEfr47u+tHe8Z5P+lZfgQbgC+gBWYH/L7mKGgr4Adku8iAA===).

Answer (score -4):

Try something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Data
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8), FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] b;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long l;
}
```

Comment: I know what you are going for, but you should add more context to explain your answer. And you should test that, because that byte array is a reference type.